# Can I create a native android app by retrieving data from Sitecore?

Tags: jss, mobile

**Current situation**

I have Sitecore 9.3. My Sitecore runs locally inside a vm. I've created a jss website and deployed it to sitecore following the official [guide](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/quick-start).

**What i want**

I want to create an android app that retrieves data from the sitecore website i've created somehow using jss. So is there any sdk for android studio java that helps me connect to sitecore?

I'm new to this enviroment and I'm not findind many resources out there about my needs. If you have done or you know anything similar it would be a great help for me to see how it was done.